# How to get a concrete row from a subquery comparing values from the main query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to get a concrete row from a subquery that returns multiple values from the value that gets the main query in which the sub is going to be called.

So this is my main query:

```
select ...
from xxxx cons
inner join  ...
inner join ...
inner join ...
```

And I want to apply this subquery into that monster:

```
(SELECT con.cs_nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cli_codigo SEPARATOR ' ') 
from trcon con 
INNER JOIN trcli clin on con.cs_nombre = clin.cli_nombre 
group by con.cs_nombre)
```

This in order to get the group_concat row from the subquery in which the cs_nombre is the same as the one that gets the main query.

Comment: What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT . . .,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT clin.cli_codigoCli SEPARATOR ' ') 
       FROM trcli clin
       WHERE clin.cli_nombre= cons.cs_nombre
      ) as cli_codigo
```

Comment: Column 'cli_codigoClinica' not found. :(

Comment: This is what I was looking for, my fault I didn't correct a simple thing of the java project! Got it! Thank you! :D